# Form, dynamic display elements

Tags: jquery

I have this form:

```
<form>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Contact form :</h1>
            <label>
                <span>Typ: </span>
                <input type="radio" name="typ" value="admin" />admin<br />
                <input type="radio" name="typ" value="user" />user<br />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>E-mail :</span>
                <input type="text" class="post" name="email" id="email"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Subject :</span>
                <input type="text" class="post" name="subject" id="subject"/>
            </label>

            <label>
                <span>If admin :</span>
                <input type="text" class="post" name="ifadmin" id="ifadmin"/>
            </label>

        </div>
    </form>
```

How to do something like that: if I choose the first radio "admin" is displayed dynamically with jquery the "ifadmin" and if I choose "user" is not displayed?

Comment: your question is hard to understand Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Yep, please try to explain better.

Comment: What have you tried? Since this is homework I'd rather not give a full code solution up front, but a general description of what you need is to create a click handler for the radio buttons that checks if the clicked one is "admin" and if so use `.show()` to make the admin elements appear, otherwise use `.hide()` to make the admin elements disappear. (Hint: It might be easier to manipulate the admin elements if you give the label element an id to select it by.)

Comment: I try something like this @nnnnnn

Comment: Something like what? You've shown the html, but please show the JavaScript / jQuery that you've been working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the id='ifadmin' to the `<label>` of ifadmin and put this code simply above the form or in the head.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("input:radio[name=typ]").click(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="admin")
    $("#ifadmin").css("display","none");
    else
    $("#ifadmin").css("display","block");
});




    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following code. Put an `class` or `id`(Which will make it easier to manipulate with jQuery) on the `ifadmin` label like

```
<label class="ifadmin">
                <span>If admin :</span>
                <input type="text" class="post" name="ifadmin" id="ifadmin"/>
            </label>
```

and `show/hide` that on the `change` callback of radio.

```
$('input[name=typ]').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'admin')
          $('.ifadmin').show();
       else
          $('.ifadmin').hide();           
    });
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/dSEzE/

Read more on [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: @CoDeaDDict, That's why I suggested him to add an id or class and added it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](http://www.diskusiweb.com/discussion/40590/enabledisable-textfield-dengan-radio-button#Item_1)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function pilihanmu(){
    var val = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < document.contoh.pilihan.length; i++ ){
        if( document.contoh.pilihan[i].checked == true ){
            val = document.contoh.pilihan[i].value;
            if(val=='3'){
                document.contoh.opsional.disabled = false;      
            }
            else{
                document.contoh.opsional.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="contoh">
    <input type="radio" name="pilihan" value="1" onclick="pilihanmu()"> Google<br>

    <input type="radio" name="pilihan" value="2" onclick="pilihanmu()"> Momonimo<br>

    <input type="radio" name="pilihan" value="3" onclick="pilihanmu()"> Lainnya..<br>

            <input type="text" name="opsional" class="text" disabled="">            
</form>
```